# What is the word that describes knowing something, but not acting on it?

Tags: single-word-requests, see-look

I'm looking for a word that describes knowing something, but not acting on it. For example:

> I know eating healthy food is good for me, but I don't do it. I'm guilty of
>   ____________.

Comment: Closest word I can think of is [repression](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/repression)

Comment: It might depend on *why* you don't do it. Can you elaborate?

Comment: You are guilty of *talking the talk but not walking the walk*.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest **inaction**

> Inaction [MASS NOUN] *Lack of action where some is expected or appropriate* [(ODO)](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/inaction)

It's simple and it implies that you should do something, i.e. eat the damn vegetables.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a case of ***procrastination***.

(Your example implies that you are somehow regretting that you are not able to put your knowledge into action; in that sense you may be indefinitely delaying it).

From [**oxforddictionaries.com**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/procrastination):

> **procrastination**
>
> *NOUN*
>
> **The action of delaying or postponing something**:
> your first tip is to avoid procrastination
>
> Indecision and inaction can lead to bigger problems in business so
> avoid procrastination and delay.
>
> As if this delay was not enough it was further compounded by
> procrastination in implementing the action recommended.
>
> Maybe it'll help a few aspiring writers realize they're not alone in
> their procrastinations.
>
> **Synonyms**:
>
> **dithering**, delaying tactics, dilatoriness, stalling, temporizing,
> **hesitation**, **vacillation**;
>
> *British*  humming and hawing; *informal* dilly-dallying, shilly-shallying
>
> *US informal* kicking the can down the road

Comment: He asked for a word. All answers look off the mark, unfortunately. Tough one.

Comment: Yes, I gave a word - procrastination. In case that was not so clear, I have edited my answer to make the word more explicit.

Comment: You are very near, but yet a wee bit far. It's like describing a tobacco or drug-addicted Dr. He knows too well, still, doesn't use his knowledge for his own benefit.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with ***apathy***.

Merriam-Webster states:

**Simple Definition** of APATHY
: the feeling of not having much emotion or interest : an apathetic state
http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/apathy

Alternatively, ***indifference*** would also work.

Merriam-Webster again:

**Simple Definition** of INDIFFERENCE
: lack of interest in or concern about something : an indifferent attitude or feeling
http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/indifference

Answer (score -2):

I think you might be looking for 'cognitive dissonance'.

Comment: Please add some explanation.